# Simple angular leaflet directive fails on start-up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet

I'm trying to implement this very simple leaflet directive for angular. (Full code is at https://github.com/pluess/woodstore).

```
class MapDirective {

    constructor() {
        this.resctrict = 'E';
        this.controller = MapController;
    }

    link(scope, element) {
        let map = L.map(element[0]).setView([30.70, -81.47], 12);

        esri.tiledMapLayer({
            url: "https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/USA_Topo_Maps/MapServer"
        }).addTo(map);
    }

    /**
     * @returns {MapDirective}
     */
    static directiveFactory() {
        return new MapDirective();
    }
}
```

When I open the application in the browser I get this error message:

```
angular.js:13708TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPane' of undefined
    at NewClass.getPane (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:60907:20)
    at NewClass._initContainer (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:61482:9)
    at NewClass.onAdd (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:61282:9)
    at NewClass.onAdd (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:55550:35)
    at NewClass._layerAdd (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:46600:10)
    at NewClass.addLayer (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:46058:10)
    at NewClass.addTo (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:60885:8)
    at MapDirective.link (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:44340:17)
    at http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:14058:19
    at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:22632:10) <map class="leaflet-container leaflet-fade-anim" tabindex="0" style="position: relative;">
```

Any ideas what's going wrong here?

Comment: Where is getPane defined? Where is it called? I don't see it on the link you provided either. You need to provide a little more code for us to figure it out.

Comment: `getPane` is in the leaflet code: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/Layer.js#L66

Comment: did you run the following commands? `npm install -g jake`
and `npm install`

Comment: Can you enable sourcemaps? Without them, reading the line numbers of `bundle.js` becomes a very hard task.

Comment: They are enabled. Unfortunately they don't help here since they are not generated for third party code comming from node_modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that by default `npm install esri-leaflet` installs version 2.0.0. This works only with leaflet 1.x which is still in beta. So the solution is to change

```
"esri-leaflet": "^2.0.0"
```

to

```
"esri-leaflet": "^1.0.2"
```